# App component not loading when running the app on ipAddress

Tags: angular

I'm running the app on host ipAddress with the following command

```
ng serve --host 10.127.153.72
```

However, App component in not initializing when I run the application as I'm setting some values into localstorage. Consoles are also not getting logged in in the `ngOnInit()` of App component. Is this an issue or am I missing something? Please suggest

Comment: Ermm.. Are you trying to run it on your localhost or something

Comment: try running - `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @wentjun I want the app to run on ipAddress, not on localhost, if I use localhost I get cross site scripting issue for APIs

Comment: Is there any error in the console when you try to access the web app?

Comment: @bracco23 no erorrs